# Windows 8 Parental Controls Time Limit Calculations

Tags: windows-8, parental-controls

I've been tasked by a parent to limit the amount of time their child can spend on their computer to 2 hours a day.

After a few days, the child reported that the timing calculation seemed off. They state that their time spent on the computer starts at when they log on, and does not take the time they're logged off into consideration.

How is their usage calculated? I can't find any authoritative answer on this from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's parental controls come with basic configuration and they are easily bypassed by children. A child can simply change the time of the clock by setting it back a few hours and they extend their time. Microsoft's Parental Controls time a session by logon events. Once the user logs on, the clock starts ticking away, sort of speak. It does not stop if the user logs off within their allowed time window.

I know you didn't ask for a recommendation, but I would recommend a third party option to better assist with parental controls.

Comment: What third party option would you recommend?

Comment: NetNanny is a popular choice. I know it can manage and restrict the amount of time a child browses the internet. Not sure if it can restrict user logons.